# Which programming language to use to interact with websites?

Tags: c++11, web

I was wondering what kind of programming language could help me to "read automatically" websites ? For instance, I would like to be able to write in code: login with this password to stack overflow, If there is any change to this page, send-me a mail...

Thanks for reading!

PS: I know some html and C++

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the language is not as important. If you build an application with Visual Basic for Windows, you can automate a Browser object to do exactly what you would do if you were navigating.
For this purposes I usually use Java, there are libraries (I personally like com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient).

Example:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
//webClient.setAppletEnabled(false);
//webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
// Get the first page
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://fist.page/address.html");
    // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
        // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
        final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("form1");
        final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("send_button");
        final HtmlTextInput input1 = form.getInputByName("input1");
        final HtmlTextInput input2 = form.getInputByName("input2");

        // Change the value of the text field
        input1.setValueAttribute("I would type this");
        input2.setValueAttribute("I would type that");

        // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
        final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

In c++, this seems to be what you need:

```
void ProgressTest(void)
{
    // Set URL and call back function.
    WinHttpClient client(L"http://www.codeproject.com/", ProgressProc);
    client.SendHttpRequest();
    wstring httpResponseHeader = client.GetResponseHeader();
    wstring httpResponseContent = client.GetResponseContent();
}
```

from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66625/A-Fully-Featured-Windows-HTTP-Wrapper-in-C

Comment: Fantastic thank you ! Do you happen to know if there is some library in C++ ?

Comment: Well, after a quick Google search you will find something.I highly recommend you to learn Java if you want to go deep into web programming. JavaScript (and/or jQuery), Android uses it, and what I like the most is the huge amount of OpenSource libraries and other programmers always willing to help.

Comment: @Pao Yes. There are C++ libraries for this. There are libraries doing this for pretty much any language that isn't called Shakespeare or LOLCODE. And even for those I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you. Could you name some libraries that can in fact generate a web browser object in C++ ? I have searched on the internet but I haven't found any yet (partly because I don't know the name of the field.. web programming ?)

Comment: I have just edited my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Having some C++ background, learning Python will be quite fast, so I recommend you giving [MechanicalSoup](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup) a try, it's a Python library that allows you to automate web actions. It's based on the already unmaintained *Mechanize*